# Rotate an object smoothly by 90 degrees on key press in unity3D

Tags: c#, unity, javascript, rotation, quaternion

[I saw few similar question on stackexchange but none is solving the purpose.]

I want to rotate a 3D object by 90 degrees on different axis on respective inputs. For example if 'a' is pressed, the object should rotate left by 90 degrees. `transform.Rotate(0,90,0);` is working but it is not rotating the object smoothly.

I am new to C# and js so cannot manually code but I tried the codes given in this answer at [Rotate an object smoothly on the Y axis in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61381/rotate-an-object-smoothly-on-the-y-axis-in-unity). The below code works but it it has two problems - 
code:

```
void Update () {
SwingOpen();
}

void SwingOpen()
{   
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.up);
    transform.rotation= Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, .05f);      
}
```

Problem 1: The above code rotates object without any keyboard inputs.
I added the condition `if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightArrow))` but now the object rotates partially on every keyboard input. I want to rotate it by 90 degrees on a single key press.

Problem 2: It will never actually rotate the object by 90 deg. It will always be tending towards 90 deg. I want exact 90 deg rotation to allow multiple 90 deg rotations for 'n' number if inputs.

How can I solve this? Please help. Please let me know if the question isn't clear enough.

[EDIT]

I applied the below script but it is giving me some totally unexpected output

Code:

```
public float speed = 1;
private int xtimesHit = 0;
private int ytimesHit = 0;
private int ztimesHit = 0;

void Update () {
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.RightArrow ) ){
        ztimesHit--;
    }
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.LeftArrow ) ){
        ztimesHit++;
    }


    if( Input.GetKeyDown( "a" ) ){
        ytimesHit++;
    }
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( "d" ) ){
        ytimesHit--;
    }


    if( Input.GetKeyDown( "w" ) ){
        xtimesHit++;
    }
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( "s") ){
        xtimesHit--;
    }

    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(xtimesHit*90,ytimesHit*90,ztimesHit*90), Time.deltaTime*speed);

}
```

On running this script
If I press rightarrow once followed by 's' the object rotates on 'z' axis and 'x' axis  correctly but there after if I press arrowkeys or 'a/s' in both the cases the object rotates on y axis. I dont understand why this is happening.

I want it to rotate w.r.t. the world axis always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it

```
private Quaternion startingRotation;
public float speed = 10;

void Start(){
    //save the starting rotation
    startingRotation = this.transform.rotation;
}

void Update () {
    //return back to the starting rotation
    if( Input.GetKeyUp( KeyCode.RightArrow ) || Input.GetKeyUp( KeyCode.LeftArrow ) ){
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(Rotate(0));
    }

    //go to 90 degrees with right arrow
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.RightArrow ) ){
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(Rotate(90));
    }

    //go to -90 degrees with left arrow
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.LeftArrow ) ){
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(Rotate(-90));
    }

}

IEnumerator Rotate(float rotationAmount){
    Quaternion finalRotation = Quaternion.Euler( 0, rotationAmount, 0 ) * startingRotation;

    while(this.transform.rotation != finalRotation){
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, finalRotation, Time.deltaTime*speed);
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

---

Edit # 1

```
public float speed = 1;
private int timesHit = 0;

void Update () {
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.RightArrow ) ){
        timesHit++;
    }
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.LeftArrow ) ){
        timesHit--;
    }

    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0,timesHit*90,0), Time.deltaTime*speed);

}
```

---

Edit #2

Perhaps like this?

```
public float speed = 1;
private GameObject endRotation;

void Start(){
    endRotation = new GameObject();
}

void Update () {
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.RightArrow ) ){
        endRotation.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 90, Space.World);
    }
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.LeftArrow ) ){
        endRotation.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, -90, Space.World);
    }


    if( Input.GetKeyDown( "a" ) ){
        endRotation.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 90, Space.World);
    }
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( "d" ) ){
        endRotation.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -90, Space.World);
    }


    if( Input.GetKeyDown( "w" ) ){
        endRotation.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, 90, Space.World);
    }
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( "s") ){
        endRotation.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, -90, Space.World);
    }

    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, endRotation.transform.rotation, Time.deltaTime*speed);

}
```

Comment: This is neither rotating smoothly not allowing multiple rotations. On first key press it rotates the objects, no actions on further key presses.

Comment: You mean like this? (see Edit #1)

Comment: I made a mistake in previous comment, edited.

Comment: Really sorry, the first code was working but i merged two script and thats why the rotation wasn't smooth. And the edit is what I was looking for. Yes! Thank you.

Comment: Np, glad I could help!

Comment: In last 5 hours I am trying to understand `Quaternion` , `Quaternion.Lerp` and `Quaternion.Euler`. Can you suggest a good place/video where I can understand it? You seem to have the concept all clear!

Comment: Quaternions can be pretty tricky. This might be a good place to start: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html and https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/quaternions

Comment: This is rotating the object in its own axis, can you tell me how can I make it rotate on the world space please?

Comment: I'd want you to take a look at the edited part of the question. :|

Comment: See edit #2. Now I have a game object that moves to the correct location instantly, and the object that is running this script moves towards that rotation slowly. Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for answering a series of such narrow questions simply to help the asker out. :P

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solution here is pretty simple - if you don't know how to write your own code yet, you should definitely take a course rather than looking up code and trying to patch it in your program somehow without knowing at all how it works.

First, delcare a variable called currentFrame, and initially set it to -1. Also, make a variable called numOfFrames, and set it to the number of frames over which the change will occur.

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && currentFrame == -1) {
        currentFrame = 0;
    }
    if(currentFrame >= 0 && currentFrame < numOfFrames) {
        SwingOpen();
        currentFrame = currentFrame + 1;
    }
}

void SwingOpen()
{   
    if (currentFrame == numOfFrames) {
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.up);
        transform.rotation = newRotation;
        currentFrame = -1;
    }
    else {
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.up);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, .05f);   
    }
}
```

Is this what you wanted? Obviously the code could probably be made cleaner but the concept will be the same.

Comment: You should never use `frames` as a counter. You always have to use `time elapsed` instead, because your code will run the game differently on devices which run on lower fps.

Comment: Well I suppose you could put this in Unity's FixedUpdate then... right? Well I'd say it depends if you care about smooth movement or consistent movement then. Personally sometimes I'd rather see my game run slower instead of choppily with sudden movements on slow devices.

Comment: @Shiro this is working but it still doesn't solve the second problem i mentioned. The object will always be tending towards 90 deg rotation, it will never complete. This will run like for ever. In short, this script does not allow three times 90 deg rotation if the key was pressed three times. It only allows once.

Comment: @SrujanBarai Oh, I see. You don't want the object to make one rotation, but rather want it to be able to make multiple 90 degree rotations. Based off of the method name SwingOpen it sounded like you wanted to program a door that could be opened multiple times. Eh... I guess I misunderstood.

Comment: Oh, just noticed, returntrue's Edit #1 could be applied to my answer too. :P

Comment: @Superdoggy Yes, returntrue's edit#1 is working but it is rotating the object on its own axis, I'm stuck on rotating it on world axis :|

Comment: @Superdoggy I'd want you to see the edit part of the question. In case you could help!